# What does # mean in Mathematica?

Tags: syntax, wolfram-mathematica

Does anyone know What # in for example `Root[-1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]` means in Mathematica?

Then what does `Root[-1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]` exactly mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

It's a placeholder for a variable.

If you want to define a y(x)=x^2 function, you just could do:

```
  f = #^2 &
```

The & "pumps in" the variable into the # sign. That is important for pairing & and # when you have nested functions.

```
  In: f[2]  
  Out: 4
```

If you have a function operating on two vars, you could do:

```
 f = #1 + #2 &
```

So

```
  In: f[3,4]  
  Out: 7
```

Or you may have a function operating in a list, so:

```
 f = #[[1]] + #[[2]] &
```

So:

```
  In: f[{3,4}]
  Out: 7
```

**About `Root[]`**

According to Mathematica help:

```
Root[f,k] represents the exact kth root of the polynomial equation f[x]==0  .
```

So, if your poly is `x^2 - 1`, using what we saw above:

```
        f = #^2 - 1 &

In[4]:= Root[f, 1]  

Out[4]= -1  (* as we expected ! *)
```

And

```
In[5]:= Root[f, 2]  

Out[5]= 1  (* Thanks God ! *)
```

But if we try with a higher order polynomial:

```
         f = -1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &  

In[6]:= Root[f, 1]

Out[6]= Root[-1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]
```

That means Mathematica doesn't know how to caculate a symbolic result. It's just the first root of the polynomial. But it does know what is its numerical value:

```
In[7]:= N@Root[-1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]

Out[7]= -2.13224
```

So, `Root[f,k]` is a kind of stenographic writing for roots of polynomials with order > 3. I save you from an explanation about radicals and finding polynomial roots ... for the better, I think

Answer (score 10):

How to find out what any built-in syntax means in Mathematica:

1. Copy expression
2. Do TreeForm[Hold[paste the expression here]].
3. Mouse-over parts of the tree to identify the syntax in question, in this case Slot
4. Enter "?Slot"

Comment: Or maybe easier: 1) Highlight 2) Press F1 3) Profit ?

Comment: That probably works most of the time. One example where TreeFor is better is when context is important, for instance if you select & on the end of function, it'll give you help for BitAnd, And and Function

Answer (score 7):

Notation `#` is (as stated above) used to mean "a variable goes here" in a pure function ("closure" for you traditional developers). It must always be followed at the end by `&`.

Best example is this: `f[x_]:=x+5`. This creates a delayed set, that any time a value is passed into a symbol reference `f` as a functional parameter, that value will be given a local context function-specific name of `x` (not affecting the global definition of `x`, if there is one). Then the expression `x+5` will be evaluated using this new variable/value.  The above process requires that symbol `f` be initialized, local variable `x` created, and expression `x+5` is permanently held in memory, unless you clear it.

**Side note:** `f=5` and `f[x_]:=5` both work with a "Symbol" `f`. `f` can be referred to as a function, when square brackets are used to extract its value, and `f[x_]` can peacefully co-exist with `f[x_,y_]` without overriding each other. One will be used when one parameter is sent, and another when 2 parameters are sent.

Some times you just need a quick function and do not need to define it and leave it hanging. So, `(someValue + 5)` becomes `(#+5)&`, where `&` says "I'm a pure function, and will work with whatever you send me", and `#` says "I'm the parameter (or a parameter list) that was sent to the pure function". You can also use `#1`, `#2`, `#3`, etc, if you're sending it more than 1 parameter.

Example of multi-parameter pure function in common use:

Let's say `mydata` is a list of lists, which you need to sort by median of the lists (e.g. housing price data from various US cities):

```
Sort[ myData , Median[#1] > Median[#2]& ]
```

Quick tip, if you're applying a function to a single value, it may look neater and cleaner, and uses less typing to use `@` instead of `[]`, which essentially means `Prefix`. Do not confuse with `Map (/@)` or `Apply(@@)`. The above command then becomes:

```
Sort[ myData , Median@#1 > Median@#2 & ]
```

You can chain `@` as such: `Reverse@Sort@DeleteDuplicates[...]`

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. Thank you. (Links to more info on the different meanings of `@` might be a good idea, though; if you're going to mention that there's several confusingly-different meanings, and further, for something that's rather hard to Google … ;)

Answer (score 4):

`#1` represents the first argument in a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

If you have multiple arguments `#1`, `#2`, `#3`...  refer to the first, second, third argument and so on.

Comment: Dear Soufiane, thanks. Then what does Root[-1 - 2 #1 - #1^2 + 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1] exactly mean?